# Обработчик события клика внутри обработчика события клика

Tags: javascript

Сделал обработчик события клика внутри обработчика события клика. Мы выбираем элемент, внутри появляется еще один элемент с кнопками, по которым мы также можем кликать. Очевидно что при повторном клике по внешнему элементу, обработчик события накидывается повторно. Я не могу сделать оба события клика в самом верху функции, поэтому мне надо чтобы этот обработчик в какой то момент снимался, но при этом я мог делать по внутренним элементам сколько угодно кликов (я попробовал поместить удаление обработчика в конце функции обработчика клика - стал срабатывать только ОДИН клик и обработчик снимался)

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.box')

buttons.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', showHidden)
})

function showHidden() {
  let hidden = document.querySelector('.hidden')

  hidden.classList.add('_active')

  let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden .btn')
  btns.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', addActive)
  })

  function addActive(e) {
    let thisBtn = e.target
    thisBtn.classList.toggle('_active')
  }
}
```

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  margin: 0 12px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: darksalmon;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
  padding: 24px;
}

.hidden._active {
  display: flex;
}

.hidden .btn {
  margin: 0 12px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden .btn._active {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="box">box 1</div>
</div>
<div class="hidden">
    <div class="btn">btn1</div>
    <div class="btn">btn2</div>
    <div class="btn">btn3</div>
    <div class="btn">btn4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Я не могу сделать оба события клика в самом верху функции," -- всё-таки это было бы лучшим решением, чем городить сложности внутри. Попробуйте сделать эту проблему отдельным вопросом. Но если никак, то временно добавляйте к стилю внешнего контейнера свойство, которое пропускает клики через себя:  `pointer-events: none;`

Comment: @DraKoan отличное решение, но по клику по этому элементу у меня снова скрываются скрытые кнопки

Comment: так же можно исследовать event.target, если в нём есть id или класс вложенного объекта, то вызывать функцию обработки вложенного контейнера, а если не содержит, то функцию внешнего.

Comment: ну и наконец, всегда можно удалять обработчики, если добавлять их через именованный коллбэк  `theElement.addEventListener(eventType, namedCallbackFn)` ... `theElement.removeEventListener(eventType, namedCallbackFn);`. В вашем случае `function addActive` каждый раз в новой области видимости `{ ..}`, эту функцию надо поднять в общую c `buttons` область

Comment: @DraKoan именно так я их и добавляю. Просто если я удаляю его в конце функции обработчика, срабатывает только первый клик и обработчик снова не навешивается. В вашем случае function addActive каждый раз в новой области видимости { ..}, эту функцию надо поднять в общую c buttons область -- сейчас попробую

Comment: Это в целом костыльный способ, но если очень хотите его, то вам надо два! обработчика. Один удаляете, второй навешиваете. По запуску есть только внешний обработчк. По его срабатыванию, он удаляется, но навешивается внутрений. В свою очередь, по его срабатываению, внутренний удаляется, и навешивается внешний. Но в целом, повторюсь, это костыльная архитектура, спагетти код. Лучше делать одноуровеный код снаружи. И исследовать event.target

Comment: @DraKoan если честно, я не очень понимаю как достать e.target ~ this из обработчика события клика. видимость у меня по нему. Как Вы наверное понимаете, у меня в проекте мильон кнопок и у каждой своя область видимости

Comment: не совсем понял, проблема в том что при клике повторно на box 1 не нажимается на btn1 btn2...?

Comment: @Dias нажимается два раза. внутренний обработчик клика навешивается повторно, вследствие чего по внутренним кнопкам срабатывает по два клика, далее по три и т. д.

Comment: вынеси let btns... и addActive() за пределы showHidden(){}

Comment: @Dias да, в данном примере так можно сделать. дело в том что у меня много таких кнопок как `box 1` и по каждой открывается свой собственный `hidden`, в котором уже кнопки `btn` и вот мне надо чтобы код работал ТОЛЬКО для тех кнопок, которые в нужном мне `hidden`. У меня не получается обойтись без контекста, а нужный мне `hidden` я нахожу именно из контекста кликнутой мной кнопки

Comment: @DraKoan решил вопрос. зарефакторил все и вынес все обработчики события наверх

Comment: @Meth0d (кстати классный ник!) Идея вообще в том, что можно (один из вариантов архитектуры поведения) делать один единственный обработчик событий на все кнопки, который умеет распознавать id кнопки и вызывать какой-то коллбек, который ему кнопка отдала во время своего создания. Этот коллбек сам отдаётся завёрнутым в стрелочную функцию `()=>{callback()}` и поэтому не теряется область видимости функции внутри кнопки. Так можно получить единый реестр всех вызовов (наглядно и удобно разом чистить всё). Но приём с коллбеком в стрелочной функции работает и из экземпляров классов.